# How to make <div> occupy the whole of the horizontal space

Tags: html, css

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Webpage </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="mydiv">
            <h1>HelloWorld!!!</h1>
        </div>
    </body>
    <style>
         body{

         }
         .mydiv{
              width:100%;
              height:10%;
              background-color:#e1e1e1;
         }
    </style>
</html>
```

Running the above lines leaves spaces left and right of it. It covers the space if i use the css below

```
    <style>
         body{
            overflow-x:hidden;
         }
         .mydiv{
              width:102%;
              height:10%;
              background-color:#e1e1e1;
              top:-7px;
              position: relative;
         }
    </style>
```

What i would like is for the div to occupy the whole horizontal screen without setting the width of the  to 102%

Thanks!

Comment: Because by default width is auto.to occupy horizontal space you need to make width 100% of it's parent

Comment: A `<div>` is a block-level element (unless you've changed its `display`), it automatically takes the full width of its parent container. You may need to set `margin: 0` and `padding: 0` on the `html`, `body` and `.mydiv` (or `div`) elements.

Comment: you have make  `padding: 0;`  `margin: 0;`  of body.

Comment: @DavidThomas You should have added your comment as answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`div` does take entire `100%` width as it is block-level element, however there is a margin/padding on body tag by default which you want to reset:

```
body {
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
}
```

Also move `style` block in the `body` or `head`, nothing is supposed to be between `</body></html>`.

Answer (score 0):

As @dfsq mention, there is no problem with your css, it's working as expected, you just need to know that in Chrome for example, the default margin for the `<body>` is `8px`.

Browsers have built-in "defaults" (and they differ from vendor to vendor) for the CSS of most HTML elements to prevents your page looking completely unreadable if you have pure HTML, but they are of course intended to be overridden by your own CSS. That's why most websites use `reset.css` or `normalize.css`.